# In TImageViewer, how to get the position where the user clicks the picture?

Tags: image, delphi, firemonkey

In the TImageViewer control, the user can zoom or pan the picture.

My question is, when the user clicks on the picture, how to get the user's click position on the picture? Especially after the user can zoom in, zoom out or pan the picture, how to get the corresponding picture click position?

As shown below:
[image]
How to know whether the user clicked on the battery position?

Demo Project:
[Demo source code](http://194.135.89.59/Image-Zoom-Demo.7z)

Comment: How do you do the zoom? Do you change the `BitmapScale` property?

Comment: @Olivier, My code is based on this demo: https://github.com/sinuke/Image-Zoom-Demo

Comment: @MartynA, MousePos returns the coordinates of the screen, not the location of the image I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't test but it should work:

```
procedure TfmMain.ivImageViewerMouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
var
    DX, DY: Single;
    ImageX, ImageY: Single;
begin
    if ivImageViewer.Bitmap.Width * ScalePicture >= ivImageViewer.Width then
        DX = ivImageViewer.ViewportPosition.X
    else
        DX := (ivImageViewer.Bitmap.Width * ScalePicture - ivImageViewer.Width)/2;
    ImageX := (X + DX) / ScalePicture;

    if ivImageViewer.Bitmap.Height * ScalePicture >= ivImageViewer.Height then
        DY = ivImageViewer.ViewportPosition.Y
    else
        DY := (ivImageViewer.Bitmap.Height * ScalePicture - ivImageViewer.Height)/2;
    ImageY := (Y + DY) / ScalePicture;
end;
```

`ImageX` and `ImageY` are the coordinates relative to the original (unscaled) image.

Comment: This does not seem to work, the calculated result is the position of the viewpoint. I uploaded my code above.

Comment: Show the values of `X`, `ivImageViewer.ViewportPosition.X`, `ScalePicture` and `ImageX`. I can't do it, I don't have Delphi here.

Comment: I didn't see you had included the executable in the archive. I tried it and there is indeed an issue when the image doesn't occupy the whole TImageViewer control. But if you zoom enough, then it does work. For example, when I click at the center of M1, I consistently get around (329, 68).

Comment: @Leo I edited the answer with a new version. Can you test it?

Comment: Excellent! Perfect solution! Thank you very much!

Comment: @Olivier:  Nice answer, +1;