# Calculate the visible area in Firemonkey's TImageViewer when zoom?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

The TImageViewer component offers zooming of an image and shows horizontal and vertical scrollbars if necessary. How can I calculate the coordinates in the source image considering the zoom and the visible image area? (e.g. when clicking into the TImageViewer). I am missing a ViewPortSize property. ViewPortPosition correctly returns the upper left corner of the image, but I can't find the height and width anywhere.

The following solution works only when not zoomed into the image. When I zoom into the image and scroll bars are displayed (with the bottom right image corner point not visible), this solution would have to take into account how large the current viewport is:

```
procedure TfmxFirebaseDemo.imvAnotateFileMouseDown(Sender: TObject;
  Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
var
  Offset: TPointF;
  Point: TPoint;
  Relative: TPointF;
  Scale: single;
begin
  Scale := 1; // imvAnotateFile.ViewportSize.X or Y in relation to current width/height;
  Offset.X := imvAnotateFile.Width - imvAnotateFile.ContentBounds.Width * Scale +
    imvAnotateFile.ViewPortPosition.X;
  Offset.Y := imvAnotateFile.Height - imvAnotateFile.ContentBounds.Height * Scale +
    imvAnotateFile.ViewPortPosition.Y;
  Point.X := round(X - Offset.X);
  Point.Y := round(Y - Offset.Y);
  Relative.X := Point.X / (imvAnotateFile.Bitmap.Width * imvAnotateFile.BitmapScale);
  Relative.Y := Point.Y / (imvAnotateFile.Bitmap.Height * imvAnotateFile.BitmapScale);
  FMX.Types.Log.d('Pos %d, %d Relative %f, %f Scale %f', [Point.X, Point.Y, Relative.X, Relative.Y, Scale]);
end;
```

Comment: It is not clear (either from the description or the sample code) what exactly you want to calculate.

Comment: @BrakNicku: Thank you for this hint: I have changed the 2nd sentence in the text: How can I calculate the coordinates in the image in the visible image area considering the zoom? (e.g. when clicking into the TImageViewer)

Comment: So if you want to translate client to bitmap coordinates, then [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61425751/3964075) does exactly this. First it calculates top left coordinates of the bitmap (the offset can be in both directions depending on the size of bitmap and the viewer), translates the mouse point and finally scales.

Comment: I saw this solution even before I opened this thread. Unfortunately, this solution does not run correctly when I zoom in and scroll into an image.

Comment: The mathematics in this answer looked OK, but now I have also tested it and got correct results for different `BitmapScale` and `ViewPortPosition` values, so if it _does not run correctly_ for you it would be useful to see the adapted code and sample obtained vs. expected results.